# gwt-dnd and dragging chess pieces

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

When a chess piece is dragged and dropped the move needs to be checked for validity.

How do I carry around the data of which of the 64 squares the original square of the piece came from and get at the data of which of the 64 squares the drop square is, all of this in the context of gwt-dnd?

I am very very new to gwt and gwt-dnd. Some pseudo code would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do similar thing but with gwtquery drag-and-drop plugin. I create a simple checker game : http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/droppable/demo/DraughtsSample/DraughtsSample.html

The code can be found there : http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/droppable/demo/DraughtsSample/DraughtsSample.html

I guess you can inspire you with what I did and adapt it to gwt-dnd...

If you want more info about gwtquery drag-and-drop plugin, just read this article : http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers